# Check recurring payment status for all installments in 2chekcout sandbox account

Tags: php, 2checkout

I want to check recurring payment status for all installments in 2Checkout sandbox account. I am not getting the notification for 2nd installment.

Answer (score 0):

The recurring and fraud tools(this generates the corresponding INS message) in Sandbox are currently not working. The 2Checkout development team is currently working to fix this issue although no ETA has been provided.

Comment: Is this still the case? I have turned demo mode off, but the Sandbox is not sending notifications.

Comment: Yes this is still the case, unfortunately. Webhooks (INS) in sandbox do not function as intended.

Comment: Most of them do, looks like just the recurring ones don't. This is really quite a big deal. It's difficult to expect people to implement your system if the implementation can't be verified properly. We've muddled through with the INS generator thing but it isn't ideal!

Comment: In the answer I stated that the recurring (fraud tools) notifications do not work. We're aware that it's not the most ideal situation, however we aren't spending any time updating the sandbox since we're working on a new platform all together. 

If you're receiving the non-recurring notifications, you shouldn't have any issues receiving the recurring notifications as 99% of the time it's the clients server rejecting the notification itself. You can always sign up for a production account and test these with small sales ($.50 cents for example.